# Finder crashes/closes when copying files to NAS

Tags: finder

OS X 10.8.2 Latest series MBP 13"

I am experiencing a problem where Finder crashes, or rather closes without notice when I move large folders into a NAS folder. (WEstern Digital Black Armor 6TB NAS drive, which is accessible just fine from the mac).

doing the same thing from the terminal using the "mv" command works perfectly. It's just Finder that makes it impossible to do it. 6 out of 10 copies will fail, leaving partial folders copies to the target.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to overcome it?

Comment: How are you connecting to your NAS? Samba, AFP, ... ?  Is it files/folders over a certain size (say, 2 GB)?

Comment: Samba, yes.
And yes. files and folders are usually >2GB.

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing a Samba limitation on the Mac side.  mv works because it's not using Samba.  You have two options: connect to your NAS using AFP (or something else) instead, or update your Samba configuration.

Check your log /var/log/samba/log.smbd for messages containing strings like "This can happen when using 64 bit lock offsets on 32 bit NFS mounted file systems."  If you have that error message, then edit the file /etc/smb.conf to contain these lines:

```
; Site-specific parameters can be added below this comment.
[Your NAS NAME]
strict locking = no ; END required configuration.
```

Comment: thanks. will give that a try today and report back here.

Comment: I don't seem to have a "samba" folder under /var/log - not even hidden. Is this where the log file is stored under OS X 10.8.2?

Comment: It should be.  You can check on your NAS too in the same location (presuming that it's a *nix-based NAS).

I generally avoid using Samba because OS X's implementation of it is buggy (a quick search on Apple's help forums will reveal the scope of the problems).  AFP works much better.

Comment: I have /var/log, just not samba under it. Not on my home 10.8 machine, not on my work 10.8 machine. In addition, using afp://<myNASname> produces an connection error. I can only use smb:// to access them, and yes, they are *nix based NAS boxes.

Comment: Seagate's knowledge base says that they have a firmware update to support AFP:
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/219975en